# "If strMyString.Contains, Then strMyString.Contains, Else Boolean" Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a-
"If strMyString.Contains, Then strMyString.Contains, Else Boolean" Procedure

*I am trying to find the name "lordgun" within a very big data Log.  For all the times it's listed, I want to list it to the right of my data.*

Here is the my whole attempt thus far-

```
Option Explicit

Public Function linecontains()lordgun As Boolean

Dim strMyString As String
Dim TargetString1 As String
Dim TargetString2 As String

'Returns True if cell contains substring, False otherwise
If strMyString.Contains("lordgun.org")

Else strMyString.Contains("") Then

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Think your code is incomplete

Comment: If all you want is a true or false then use native worksheet formula like `=isnumber(search("lordgun", a2))`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the instr function.

This function returns an int. If it returns a value > 0 then the string was found.
e.g:

```
If Instr(1, MyString, SearchFor, 0) >0  Then

Else

End if
```